# Goland auto populates the global search bar with text

Tags: ide, golang

**Goland Version:**

2018.2.4

**How to Reproduce the Error**:

When I press command+shift+f to open the global finder in Goland it auto populates with the same text each time:

[Window showing text auto populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm4xm.png)

Regardless if I have text highlighted or not before I execute the global search it will always replace the text and insert this same value each time.

**Question:**

Any help or ideas? Has anyone seen any similar behavior with their Goland before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the OpenPGP client for mac in running in the background and that sets a system-wide shortcut to fill in that, it's a known issue.

Either disable that agent, change its shortcut or change the shortcut in GoLand.

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-6576 for details.

And as a side-note, you should consider upgrading to GoLand 2018.3.3 as that's the latest IDE version.

Comment: Yes worked like a charm!! Thank you so much!